# IE8 AngularJS directive call .getContext on canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, internet-explorer-8, directive

I'm currently using AngularJS 1.4.7 and I'm trying to integrate Chartjs. Everything works as expected in most modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE 9 >, etc). However I got a problem with IE8.

My current setup is that I've created an directive on the canvas element. Which calls the scoped method donutify.

```
 app.directive('donutify', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var def = {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.donutify(attrs.id)
            }, 0);
        }
    };
    return def;
}]);
```

In the **donutify** method I'm trying to access the method of the current canvas.

```
$scope.donutify = function (id)
    {
        var donut = $("#" + id);

        if (donut.length)
        {
            var context = donut.get(0).getContext("2d");
        ...
```

This works in all browser except in IE8. If I print out the **donut** object, I can see it exists, however it doesn't has the getContext method available. The error message thrown in console is:

**TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method**

Can anyone help?

Comment: Angular droppped support for IE8 since version 1.3 . And chart js's documentation mentions you might need to use the ExplorerCanvas polyfill to get canvas to work on IE8. Have you already checked this?

Comment: I'm using a build for IE8 (AngularJS v1.4.7-ie8), and I'm already using the ExplorerCanvas polyfill. The rendering of Chartjs works when I render it without using a directive.